# Discord.py Different variable for all users

Tags: python, variables, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make some kind of "strength stat" in an RPG server. But I need this variable to be different for each user. I've searched and I could only find a variable different for a list of users, not all of them.

Comment: are you looking for a [dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)?

Comment: Not at all, as I said, I need ALL users on the server. Maybe it's possible to make a dictionary with all of them?

Comment: Of course it’s possible, do you know how a dict works?

Comment: I would save it in a json file to persist it when the bot restarts..

Comment: As @Łukasz Kwieciński suggested you should use a dictionary, but you should better know what a dictionary is before.

Answer (score 0):

## `Dict`ionaries

---

[`Dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)s...

> are the Python implementation of an abstract data type, known in computer science as an associative array. [[]](https://python-course.eu/python-tutorial/dictionaries.php)

> Associative arrays consist - like dictionaries of (`key`, `value`) pairs, such that each possible key appears at most once in the collection.

---

I would suggest to create a dictionary written this way:

```
{
    "ID of the user": [first_stat, second_stat]
}
```

Then you can store it in a `.json` file with the [`Python`'s `JSON` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), to preserve datas after bot restart:

```
async def on_ready():
    with open("stats.json", 'r') as stats:
        stats = json.load(stats)
```